# Edit text in android

Tags: android

Hi am having one Edit Text which is used to get the information about the user.i have set the following properties to edit text

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/profile_about"
        android:layout_below="@id/AboutYou"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="18dip"
        android:gravity="top|left"
        android:inputType="textCapWords"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:background="@drawable/edittext"     

        android:layout_width="300dip" 
        android:layout_height="100dip"
        android:textSize="16sp"
    />
```

the problem is it scrolls horizontal only.not go the newline after entering certain characters.can anybody help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I replaced `android:inputType="textCapWords"` by     `android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapWords"`, and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `android:singleLine="false"`

Answer (score 0):

android:singleLine="false"
if this property is set then the charecters after a certain limit will go to next line automatically...
try this too
 android:scrollHorizontally="false"